# RPi Unistalling All Upgraded Packages

Tags: raspbian-stretch, sudo, software-compilation

After following this article, https://askubuntu.com/questions/101802/packages-having-unmet-dependencies-broken-packages, to fix an issue on my RPi when compiling QEMU, I ran `sudo apt-get remove glib2*` and it started to remove all upgraded packages. Can I simply fix this by running `sudo apt-get upgrade` or is there something else I need to do.

#### Edit One

Also it uninstalled Chromium, but I am posting this from Chromium; how does this work???

#### Edit Two

The operation was interrupted and I got:
`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned error code (1)`
`W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish`

Now my computer is missing some of its icons and some of the programs are missing. Some icons look different. Chromium is still running even though it was supposedly uninstalled.

#### Edit Three

I have now also run `sudo apt-get -f install` and `sudo apt-get update` to no avail and am now running `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: As your system seems to be in an unknown state, I would suggest reflashing the SD card and starting fresh. Not doing so you risk a whole series of difficult to debug issues and lots of frustration.

Comment: What is glib2*? On my Raspbian Stretch I do not find any packet that is named glib2*; looked with `apt list glib2*`. Chromium still works because its deinstallation was interrupted as you wrote. Now you have a half installed Chromium. It is integral part of the GUI. Deinstalling it is the hard way to learn that it breaks your system.

Comment: @Ingo Don't do this, but if you run `sudo apt-get install glib2*`, it will install all the files that begin with `glib2`.

Comment: @Ingo @Steve Robillard Could it be because regex parsed the `*` in `glib2*` as delete all packages.

Comment: As I told there are no packets beginning with `glib2*` in the default Raspbian Stretch repository so I cannot install them even if I wish. Where do you get it from? Btw. the best is what Steve suggested: reflash.

Comment: @Ingo - what makes you say that Chromium is an **integral** part of the GUI? I've never seen any mention anywhere that the GUI on Pi **requires** anything at all related to chromium

Comment: @JaromandaX Isn't it? OK, I rarely use the GUI. I only had a short look at the dependendies ...

Comment: If anyone wants to try this on a spare RPi lying around, go ahead. Enter `sudo apt-get install glib2*`. All it does is install all the packages related to glib2. Which is probably why it installed all the packages that started with glib2. But when I deleted it, why did it almost delete everything else? Shouldn't regex stop that from happening. Isn't that why you only put a `*` when you mean everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just flash your RPI with Rapsbian again.